# Fill up empty space in flexbox image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am have this HTML/CSS gallery using flexbox.

```css
@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props";
@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props/normalize.min.css";

:root {
  --magnifier: 6;
  --gap: 1vmin;
  --transition: 0.5s;
}
  
.gallery {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.child {
  transition: flex var(--transition), filter var(--transition);
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.child:hover {
  flex: var(--magnifier);
}

img {
  --brightness: 0.85;
  --grayscale: 1;
  height: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(var(--grayscale)) brightness(var(--brightness));
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:hover {
  --brightness: 1;
  --grayscale: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/572897/pexels-photo-572897.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7604425/pexels-photo-7604425.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4666748/pexels-photo-4666748.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4932184/pexels-photo-4932184.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4210900/pexels-photo-4210900.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3126574/pexels-photo-3126574.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/167699/pexels-photo-167699.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1376201/pexels-photo-1376201.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2437291/pexels-photo-2437291.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1679772/pexels-photo-1679772.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1183099/pexels-photo-1183099.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1813513/pexels-photo-1813513.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
  <div class="child"><a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/931018/pexels-photo-931018.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a></div>
 </div>
```

The portrait images have empty space when hovering. I was hoping `object:cover` would fill it up but it doesn't quite work. What is the best way to fill up the empty space?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` and `<img>` also need to be `width:100%` and `height:100%;`

```css
@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props";
@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props/normalize.min.css";
 :root {
  --magnifier: 6;
  --gap: 1vmin;
  --transition: 0.5s;
}

.gallery {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.child {
  transition: flex var(--transition), filter var(--transition);
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.child:hover {
  flex: var(--magnifier);
}

.child a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  --brightness: 0.85;
  --grayscale: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(var(--grayscale)) brightness(var(--brightness));
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:hover {
  --brightness: 1;
  --grayscale: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/572897/pexels-photo-572897.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7604425/pexels-photo-7604425.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4666748/pexels-photo-4666748.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4932184/pexels-photo-4932184.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4210900/pexels-photo-4210900.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3126574/pexels-photo-3126574.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/167699/pexels-photo-167699.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1376201/pexels-photo-1376201.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2437291/pexels-photo-2437291.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1679772/pexels-photo-1679772.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1183099/pexels-photo-1183099.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1813513/pexels-photo-1813513.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/931018/pexels-photo-931018.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `object-fit` to work, you need to style your image elements with a definite width and height. Yours have a definite height, but you have not specified a width. In the absence of definite dimensions, all the browser has to work with are the intrinsic dimensions of the source image.

As per @Shuo’s answer, in your design your `.child` divs have their widths determined by the flexbox `.gallery`, so their widths are definite. But neither the anchor element nor the image element inside them have been assigned a width. Set the width of both to 100% and your problem will be solved.